# Bootstrap dropdown list position (Up/Bottom) based on document height

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap dropmenu list on my page. When page is minimized or screen is adjusted, the menulist is going off the screen. I want to check and display them in upwards if screen height is making the list going off the screen.

here is my html,

```
 <div  class="btn-group pull-right">                    
 <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Click<span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul  class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second></li>
                    <li>Third</li>
                    <li><Fourth</li>
                    <li>Fifth</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Note: List is going off in respective to height, not width. Width of the screen doesn't matter because i am already using "pull-right" which makes my list display inside the screen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To cause a dropdown menu to instead display upwards when its toggle control is clicked, you should use the `.dropup` class on the menu's container element. To determine when to apply this class, you can calculate whether the bottom of the expanded dropdown will end up below the window, and if it does, apply the `.dropup` class.

One possible implementation of this (attached to the window's `scroll` event):

```
function determineDropDirection(){
  $(".dropdown-menu").each( function(){

    // Invisibly expand the dropdown menu so its true height can be calculated
    $(this).css({
      visibility: "hidden",
      display: "block"
    });

    // Necessary to remove class each time so we don't unwantedly use dropup's offset top
    $(this).parent().removeClass("dropup");

    // Determine whether bottom of menu will be below window at current scroll position
    if ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() > $(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()){
      $(this).parent().addClass("dropup");
    }

    // Return dropdown menu to fully hidden state
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
  });
}

determineDropDirection();

$(window).scroll(determineDropDirection);
```

Here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rKWaraSvbI) to demonstrate. Try making the demo panel shorter, and then scroll the panel up and down to see how the dropdown menu will appear above/below its toggle control depending on the available space it has.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great, works as expected. And also I added $(window).resize(determineDropDirection);

So that it will behave in same manner when window is resized.

Comment: Happy to help, glad you were able to adapt it to your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Solves a very common problem indeed!

Comment: May I know why we put css(Line 5 - Line 8) in this function instead of in the css file?

Comment: @Meilan We're only temporarily applying the styles so we can determine the dimensions of the dropdown; we don't want them to always be applied (like if they were defined in a stylesheet). After our calculations, the inline styles are removed again by `removeAttr("style")`.

Comment: @Serlite  Thank you, may I know why we use $(window).scrollTop() here?

Comment: @Meilan Take a look at the [jQuery docs for scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/). We're using it here to get the current vertical scroll position of the window, so that in conjunction with the dimensions of the dropdown and the window, we can figure out if there's enough space below the dropdown to show it extending downwards.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a click event based on @Serlite solution in case you just want to execute the code if any dropdown menu is clicked:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[data-toggle=dropdown]', function(){
    var dropmenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');

    dropmenu.css({
        visibility: "hidden",
        display: "block"
    });

    // Necessary to remove class each time so we don't unwantedly use dropup's offset top
    dropmenu.parent().removeClass("dropup");

    // Determine whether bottom of menu will be below window at current scroll position
    if (dropmenu.offset().top + dropmenu.outerHeight() > $(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()){
        dropmenu.parent().addClass("dropup");
    }

    // Return dropdown menu to fully hidden state
    dropmenu.removeAttr("style");
});
```